# C++ Function Template Error with namespace

Tags: c++, function, templates

I am getting an error while writing a simple function template. I would appreciate if someone can tell me what am I doing wrong.

Errors:

```
z:\n4\pkg\mrservers\mrimaging\seq\cestipat_offsetseries\GlobalVariable.h(118) : error C2825: 'type1': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
z:\n4\pkg\mrservers\mrimaging\seq\cestipat_offsetseries\GlobalVariable.h(118) : error C2039: 'const_iterator' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
z:\n4\pkg\mrservers\mrimaging\seq\cestipat_offsetseries\GlobalVariable.h(118) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'i1'
```

……
My function is as follows (I have marked the line no. where the error shows up)

```
template<typename type1>
void PrintVector(type1 VectorIn_1) {    
    long lLenghtVec = VectorIn_1.size();
    typename type1::const_iterator  i1 = VectorIn_1.begin();    // line 118
    for(int i = 0; i != lLenghtVec; ++i){               // line 119
        std::cout << std::setw(4) << *i1 << " " <<std::endl;    
        ++i1;
    }
}
```

Namespace used:
In the beginning, I have used ARMADILLOS lib

```
#include <armadillo>.
#define ARMA_64BIT_WORD
#include "armadillo-3-910-0/include/armadillo"
using namespace arma;
```

Comment: how do you call this function? (so, what is the type of _type1_ ?)
i suspect it is not a container type

Comment: it means that type1 has no such type const_iterator. Maybe you try to call your function with POD?

Comment: BTW, you may pass by const reference to avoid useless copies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling your template correctly (presumably passing a non-type, but you did not show the call site), the following [compiles and run fine](http://ideone.com/THP53S) (I did not modify your function) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

template<typename type1>
void PrintVector(type1 VectorIn_1) {    
    long lLenghtVec = VectorIn_1.size();
    typename type1::const_iterator  i1 = VectorIn_1.begin();    // line 118
    for(int i = 0; i != lLenghtVec; ++i){               // line 119
        std::cout << std::setw(4) << *i1 << " " <<std::endl;    
        ++i1;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4};
    PrintVector<std::vector<int>>(v);
}
```

**Note:**

- You should prefer passing iterators rather than containers to your functions, it makes your code more generic (i.e. ala C++ Standard Library)

Comment: Obligatory remark regarding "STL": [It Is Not Called The "STL", Mmkay?](http://kera.name/articles/2010/08/it-is-not-called-the-stl-mmkay/)

Comment: @quantdev I think you are right. Somehow there was problem with my class. It's working now.